# Problem: Traffic Flow

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have the following task:

> The Shallow Alto city council has organized a special committee to
>   review the traffic situation in the city. Despite the fact that there
>   is nothing whatsoever to do in the city, citizens still write
>   complaints about the amount of time it takes them to get from one
>   unexciting location to the next. The committee has been asked to
>   figure out how long it takes someone to travel down the streets of
>   Shallow Alto given the current traffic light programming. To do this,
>   they want you to write an algorithm which, given the speed a car
>   travels down a road and the timing of the traffic lights, returns the
>   amount of time it takes the car to travel down the street. The traffic
>   lights will be in an int[], with each element representing the amount
>   of time in seconds between signal changes. Initially, all traffic
>   lights have just turned green, and are at the beginning of their
>   cycle. The order of the traffic lights in the int[] will be the order
>   in which a car encounters them. The speed you will be given is in
>   meters per second. Assume that the car starts 150 meters before the
>   first traffic light, that there are 150 meters between each traffic
>   light, and that the car stops 150 meters after the last traffic light.
>   Disregard all acceleration and deceleration; a car is either at its
>   given speed or entirely stopped, and it takes no time to go from one
>   state to the other. If a car reaches a traffic light just as it turns
>   red, it immediately stops and waits for it to turn green again (at
>   which point it starts moving immediately). If the light just turned
>   green, there is no wait and the car drives on through. Return the
>   time, in seconds, that it takes the car to travel the entire distance.
>   Round down any fractional parts, (for example 55.5 becomes 55 and 44.9
>   becomes 44), but do not do this until returning.

This is my first draft:

```
public class Car
{
    public double Speed { get;set; }

}
```

```
public class Light
{        
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public double SwitchTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsGreen(double time)
    {
        double num = Math.Floor(time / SwitchTime);

            return num % 2 == 0;            
    }
    public double TimeToWait(double time)
    {
        if (!IsGreen(time))
        {
            return ((time % SwitchTime) < 0.01) ? SwitchTime : (time % SwitchTime);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

```
class Traffic
{
    public Car mycar;
    public IList<Light> LightList;
    public static double lengthbetweenLights { get; set; }

    public double getTravelTime()
    {
        double currenttime = lengthbetweenLights / mycar.Speed;            

        foreach (Light light in LightList)
        {               
            currenttime += lengthbetweenLights / mycar.Speed + light.TimeToWait(currenttime);                
        }

        return currenttime;
    }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var car1 = new Car
        {
            Speed = 20
        };
        List<Light> lights1 = getLightList();

        var mytraffic = new Traffic
        {
            mycar = car1,
            LightList = lights1

        };

        Traffic.lengthbetweenLights = 150; 

        var traveltime = mytraffic.getTravelTime();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Time for car: {0}", traveltime));
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }

    private static List<Light> getLightList()
    {
        List<Light> lstProducts = new List<Light>();
        //input 1
        lstProducts.Add(new Light { Number = 0, SwitchTime = 10 });
        lstProducts.Add(new Light { Number = 1, SwitchTime = 20 });
        lstProducts.Add(new Light { Number = 2, SwitchTime = 30 });
        return lstProducts;
    }


}
```

You can also see my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexan1/DotNetTest/tree/master/TrafficFlow).

I need to improve my code, make it more OOP and use Design Patterns.

Question is: which design patterns I can use here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Naming

I strongly recommend you read through the official [C# naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Here are a few rules to keep in mind:

- Properties are UpperCamelCase
- Private fields are lowerCamelCase, sometimes prepended with an underscore
- Methods are UpperCamelCase
- Local variables are lowerCamelCase
- Test methods should be descriptive [[more information]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47660/writing-better-junit-tests/47666#47666)

Applied to your code, here are a few changes to make:

- `TestMethod1` -> `TimeToWait_WithFiveMinutes_ShouldReturnZero`
- `mycar` -> `currentCar`
- `lengthbetweenLights` -> `lengthBetweenLights`
- `getTravelTime` -> `GetTravelTime`

Also keep in mind that your naming should make sense in light of the contest: `MyCar` does not really make sense in the sense of a `Traffic` analysis: what if I want to calculate it with someone else's car? Therefore I suggest making it `CurrentCar` instead.

This is part of the encapsulation I talk about next, but keep in mind that hiding the implementation details by not putting them in the variable's name, is also a form of encapsulation.

Right now you have a variable named `LightList` which tells me that it concerns a list of lights. Except, I already know it's a list because I can see the type. But what if you want to go more general and make it a `ICollection` instead? Or you want to group them with the amount of dogs that peed against it: `Dictionary<Light, int>`. Now your name doesn't fit anymore and you'll have to change it (and make version control ugly).

Methods are actions: you perform an action on the instance. What kind of action is `TimeToWait`? I would have expected it to be a property from the way it's worded. `GetTimeToWait` makes it clear that I will receive a value (and just that).

## Encapsulation

Definitely read more on the topic of [*encapsulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), a cornerstone of OO-Programming. Your `Traffic` class has public fields which are open for modification. By forcing to do this through setters (an auto-generated property is a setter!) you can satisfy encapsulation and force whoever wants to modify it to go through your setter first. This means that you can add validation logic before touching the backing variable.

Instead what you should do is work with a public property like

```
public Car CurrentCar { get; set; };
```

[[More information on fields and properties]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714081/oop-confusion-in-classes/20714233#20714233)

## Events

Traffic lights that get their status updated every second sounds like a good option to put [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in here. You could keep counters `elapsedTime` and `switchTime` and a flag `isGreen` so your light can articulate its state to callers. This would make your methods `IsGreen()` and `GetTimeToWait()` more intuitive: you don't have to call them with an argument to signify the current time.

Although this might be overdoing the assignment a little bit.

Comment: +1 for grouping traffic lights by the number of dogs that peed against it. Priceless! ;)

Comment: what about design patterns? can they be used here?

Comment: Your code is too minor to identify a possibility for a design pattern; I can't see any.

Comment: There is no such thing as upper/lower camel case. There's Pascal case and camel case

Comment: Call it whatever you like, this is a clear separation and both are widely spread. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms